# How to call JavaScript object methods in one statement (Method Chaining)

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I made an object inside function. I want to call object methods in one
statement.

```css
(function(){
        s4 = function(getSection){
            var self = {
            name: function(getname){
                console.log("Name of the Student " +getname);
            },

            subject: function(getsub){
                console.log(" & Studying " +getsub);
            }

        }
     return self;   
        }
    })();
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student Details</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="hello">
      <h1>Student Details</h1>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
        s4("5th").name("John"); //This works fine
        s4("5th").subject("Python"); //This works fine
        s4("5th").name("John").subject("Python"); //Shows error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'subject' of undefined or null reference


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I call `s4("5th").name("John").subject("Python");` 
Shows error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'subject' of undefined or null reference

Please help me solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because name function is not returning anything

Comment: @jeffcarey is correct. Name function is not returning any object, that's why you are getting null or undefined reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your methods, return the object. `return this` in `name` and `subject.` This is called method chaining and it works by returning an object.

```js
(function() {
  s4 = function(getSection) {
    var self = {
      name: function(getname) {
        console.log("Name of the Student " + getname);
        return this;
      },
      subject: function(getsub) {
        console.log(" & Studying " + getsub);
        return this;
      }
    }
    return self;
  }
})();

s4("5th").name("John");
s4("5th").subject("Python");
s4("5th").name("John").subject("Python");
```

Answer (score 2):

That is called [method chaining](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) and is normally achieved by making each function that doesn't return some other value, `return this;`:

```
name: function(getname){
    console.log("Name of the Student " +getname);
    return this;
},

subject: function(getsub){
    console.log(" & Studying " +getsub);
     return this;
}
```

Then `s4("5th").name("John").subject("Python");` will work since `name("John")` returns the result of `s4("5th")`.

Comment: Can we concatenate both methods while calling method in a chain

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
(function() {
  s4 = function(getSection) {
    var self = {
      name: function(getname) {
        console.log("Name of the Student " + getname);
        return this;
      },
      subject: function(getsub) {
        console.log(" & Studying " + getsub);
        return this;
      }
    }
    return self;
  }
})();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Student Details</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Student Details</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    s4("5th").name("John"); //This works fine
    s4("5th").subject("Python"); //This works fine
    s4("5th").name("John").subject("Python"); //Shows error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'subject' of undefined or null reference
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And now you will not get error for calling function `subject()`

Answer (score -1):

Your function

```
name: function(getname){
        console.log("Name of the Student " +getname);
    }
```

does not return `this`.
Change it to:

```
name: function(getname){
        console.log("Name of the Student " +getname);
        return this;
    }
```